# ZeroMQ Java Binding LD_LIBRARY_PATH

Tags: java, unix, centos, zeromq, unsatisfiedlinkerror

I'm trying to use ZeroMQ on CentOS.

I followed the install [instructions for unix like platforms](http://www.zeromq.org/bindings%3ajava)

I keep getting the following exception when running:

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no jzmq in java.library.path
```

However the following line fixes this problem:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib
```

What exactly is this LD_LIBRARY_PATH and why is not explained in the install instructions? Do I need to run this export everytime?

Answer (score 3):

It's a way to specify where to load some native library (.so file) the app is using.  You can get that variable defined in the environment in a number of ways, depending on what you need.  If you are going to have the MQ start when the os boots, you could put the export in the startup shell script.  Or it might go in /etc/bashrc, or it might go in ~/.bashrc  It just depends on what you need.

FYI I don't know anything about ZeroMQ itself.